# Error "Cannot modify this web hosting plan because another operation is in progress" Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

We are using Powershell SDK to write our infrastructure as code in Azure. For the DEV instance, we are deleting the Resource group first and then completely provision and redeploy our application.

Doing that I get often the error message "Cannot modify this web hosting plan because another operation is in progress". A workaround is to add a Sleep after this command and then hope its done continue with the script.

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -ErrorVariable GetResourceGroupError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if(!$GetResourceGroupError -and $PeformCleanDeployment)
{
    Write-Output "Removing resources group..."
    Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Force
    do
    {
        Write-Output "Waiting until resource group is deleted..."
        Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -ErrorVariable GetResourceGroupError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Start-Sleep 30
    } while (!$GetResourceGroupError)
}
```

But this is not working. I still get the error.

What is the recommended way doing this? Is there an option to ensure the Resource Group is Really gone?

My Resource Group contains a webapp, serviceplan and a postgres database.

Error message I get

```
Removing resources group...
True
Waiting until resource group is deleted...
Wait ----
Creating resources...
ResourceGroupName : ####################
Location          : westeurope
ProvisioningState : Succeeded
Tags              :
ResourceId        : ####################

New-AzureRmAppServicePlan : Cannot modify this web hosting plan because another operation is in progress. Details: Id:
########################, OperationName: Delete, CreatedTime: 10/4/2017 8:32:32 AM, RequestId:
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> What is the recommended way doing this? Is there an option to ensure
>   the Resource Group is Really gone?

You could use [`Get-AzureRmResourceGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/AzureRM.Resources/Get-AzureRmResourceGroup?view=azurermps-4.4.0) to determine whether resource group exist.

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $rgname -ev notPresent -ea 0

If ($notPresent)
{
    Write-host "not exist"
}else
{
    Write-host "exist"
}
```

Here is my test result.

[image]

According to your scenario, if resource group exist, you need continue wait.

Update: I modify your script as below: it works for me.

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $myResourceGroup -ErrorVariable GetResourceGroupError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if(!$GetResourceGroupError)


{
    Write-Output "Removing resources group..."
    Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $myResourceGroup -Force
    do
    {
        Write-Output "Waiting until resource group is deleted..."
        Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $myResourceGroup -ErrorVariable GetResourceGroupError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        "Wait ----"
        Start-Sleep 5

    } while (!$GetResourceGroupError)
}
```

Another solution you could use dynamic name(Random name).

Comment: I try to do the same. I have updated my post with the script I use. But still get the error

Comment: @aumanjoa I run your script, it seems it does not go into remove steps and exit, so you get the error log.

Comment: @aumanjoa It seems your script did nothing. it could not delete resource group, if possible, you could test my answer. I think it will work for you.

Comment: unfortunately it's not working. I have added my error log.

Comment: @aumanjoa Sorry for the later response. Do you try use dynamic name. It is very strange, I could delete the resource group and re-create them. When you delete your resource group, do you check it on Azure Portal, web app plan exist?

Comment: yes seems to be solved. I think the azure team did some rework